# Is there a way to sort all custom layers by type on the z axis in Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have about 20 layers with different types.
I want all layers of type "symbol" to be always on top of the z-axis.
Below the "symbol" Layer should always be "point" and "line" Layer.

Is there a way to quickly sort all layers by type on the z-axis after adding the layers in Mapbox or do I have to arrange each Layer with map.moveLayer('myLayer')?

Comment: Simply add the layer's you want to add on the top at the last i.e the layer you add first will be at the bottom and the layer you add at the last will be on top

Comment: Good point. however, the layers are changed and adjusted frequently.... I would like to prevent the error proneness if there is a quick solution for this.

Comment: I believe there is no other way apart from maintaining layer order while adding, you have to use moveLayer https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/7016#issuecomment-598452713